# Compiling failure code from Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

Tags: c++, opengl

I began the tutorial found  here (http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/).

I have followed all of the step in the Building the Tutorials page but when I try to compile the first tutorial project I get the

`warning : The referenced project 'framework\framework.vcxproj' does not exist.`

and the

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup`
This is one of my first steps out of console programming so I am sure I am missing something obvious.
I am building it on Visual Studios 2012 Ult on a Windows 8 machine.

I am sure I am missing the information you need for me to solve the problem so please let me know what exact information you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need a main() function so the program knows where to start.

Answers for the same problem as yours can be found here:
[error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845410/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-main-referenced-in-function-tmainc)

Comment: The code I am using is built by the guy who made the tutorial.  He using a main that is a separate file called framework.  And each project uses that, I'm not sure how it works (or lack there of).

Comment: @HunterO'Rourke: Well, then I suggest you read up on the topics of *compilation units* and *linking*. Also I suggest you read and try to understand the arcsynthesis framework.