# LNK2019 Error Cocos2D-X

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I got a LNK2019 error in Visual Studio 2013 when I changed a file.
When you create a new Cocos2D-X project you start with a basic project with 2 cpp files and 2 header files.

I changed the HelloWorldScene (header & cpp) file to another name. Now I am getting a LNK2019 error :

```
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup   C:\Users\bette_000\Documents\GitHub\TheAdventuresOfJos\MyGame\proj.win32\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj)    MyGame
Error   6   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\bette_000\Documents\GitHub\TheAdventuresOfJos\MyGame\proj.win32\Debug.win32\MyGame.exe 1   1   MyGame
```

I used to have these files:

- AppDelegate.cpp (& .h)
- BeginMenu.cpp (& .h)
- globals.h
- HelloWorldScene.cpp (& .h)
- OptionsMenu.cpp (& .h)

This worked. But since I changed the name of HelloWorldScene.cpp (& .h) to MainApp.cpp (& .h) I got this error.

Comment: Well, I'd be looking at this `_main` symbol that you've referenced somewhere. Did you mean `_tmain` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps somehow your linker settings got confused, try

```
Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System
```

and change SubSystem to Console.

[Original post in stackoverflow for this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845410/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-main-referenced-in-function-tmainc)

Comment: I don't see why that would do it since I only changed a name of a file? I'll look into it though!