# cpp File not compiling with cl, but compiles just fine inside Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, cl

I'm having an issue where the following code can't be compiled using CL (VS CMD).
Instead of Compiling, it gives me Error LN2019.
Compiling the same Code inside VS, compiles without errors.

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK
MainWindowCallback( HWND   Window,
                    UINT   Message,
                    WPARAM WParam,
                    LPARAM LParam)
{
    LRESULT Result = 0;

    switch(Message)
    {
        case WM_SIZE:
        {
            OutputDebugStringA("WM_SIZE\n");
        } break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            OutputDebugStringA("WM_DESTROY\n");
        } break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            OutputDebugStringA("WM_CLOSE\n");
        } break;

        case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
        {
            OutputDebugStringA("WM_ACTIVATEAPP\n");
        } break;

        default:
        {
            // OutputDebugSTringA("default\n")
            Result = DefWindowProc(Window, Message, WParam, LParam);
        } break;
    }

    return(Result);
}

int CALLBACK
WinMain(HINSTANCE Instance,
        HINSTANCE PrevInstance,
        LPSTR     CommandLine,
        int       ShowCode)
{
    WNDCLASS WindowClass = {};

    WindowClass.style = CS_OWNDC|CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = MainWindowCallback;
    WindowClass.hInstance = Instance;
    // WindowClass.hIcon;
    WindowClass.lpszClassName = "FooWindowClass";

    return(0);
}
```

I tracked down the issue to Line 36:

```
Result = DefWindowProc(Window, Message, WParam, LParam);
```

When i comment this line out, the file compiles just fine.
The cl command used to Compile is also pretty standard:

```
cl -Zi Foo.cpp
```

Is there some cl parameter i missed?

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: From the prefix `LN`, I'm guessing this is a linker error: where is `DefWindowProc` defined?

Comment: You are missing a lot of switches that VisualStudio passes to cl.  One of the project properties page(s) shows the generated command line.

Comment: If you receive an error, post the **entire** error message, unmodified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must link with user32.lib:

```
cl Foo.cpp user32.lib
```

Comment: Yes, this did it.
Figured it would be a parameter like that.
Any idea why it wouldn't automatically include user32.lib when using cl? Unlike in VS itself?

Comment: @kazaamjt: Visual Studio doesn't automatically include any arguments to CL either. It uses those **you** specified in the project settings.

Answer (score -1):

Error `Error LN2019` is not having a "main" (you seem to have named it `WinMain`).

See also: [error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845410/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-main-referenced-in-function-tmainc)