# unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup of dlls

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I have written the following code as a sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE arg_instance, DWORD arg_reason, LPVOID arg_reserved)
{
    switch(arg_reason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: puts("DllMain called for DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH"); break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: puts("DllMain called for DLL_PROCESS_DETACH"); break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Then I try to link it with the following command:

> link DllWithEntryPoint.obj /DLL /ENTRY:DllMain

It gives me the following errors:

> LIBCMT.lib(crt0.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main
> referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup something.dll : fatal error
> LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Where is my mistake and how can I link it correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol \_main referenced in function \_\_\_tmainCRTStartup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845410/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-main-referenced-in-function-tmainc)

Comment: No, it doesn't work. @SimonMourier

Comment: You are missing the [/DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dll-build-a-dll) linker option. Once that is fixed make sure to remove the `/ENTRY` option. It's probably not what you want when linking against the CRT.

Comment: Contrary to its name, DllMain is not actually a usable entrypoint for a DLL.  It is very important that *first* the C and C++ runtime libraries get initialized, then it is safe for the runtime library to invoke DllMain().  You'll have to do this without the /ENTRY option.  Or write code that doesn't use the runtime libraries at all, that's very hard to do.